# /dev/urandom error (permission denied by webhost)

Tags: php, random, code-generation

I am using function:

```
private function random($len) {
        if (@is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
            $f=fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
            $urandom=fread($f, $len);
            fclose($f);
        }

        $return='';
        for ($i=0;$i<$len;++$i) {
            if (!isset($urandom)) {
                if ($i%2==0) mt_srand(time()%2147 * 1000000 + (double)microtime() * 1000000);
                $rand=48+mt_rand()%64;
            } else $rand=48+ord($urandom[$i])%64;

            if ($rand>57)
                $rand+=7;
            if ($rand>90)
                $rand+=6;

            if ($rand==123) $rand=52;
            if ($rand==124) $rand=53;
            $return.=chr($rand);
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

I have some forms which trigger this function and I get the error:

> int(2) string(200) "is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed path(s):

Is there a way to replace this function and not to use `/dev/urandom` ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the (previously accepted) answer:

> Instead of urandom you can use "rand":

Nooooooooo!

---

Dealing with open_basedir is one of the things we handle gracefully in [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat). Seriously consider importing that library then just using `random_bytes()` instead of reading from /dev/urandom.

Whatever you do, [DON'T USE `rand()`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php). Even if you believe there's a use case for it, [the security trade-offs are a lie](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/12/let-s-re-think-security-trade-offs).

Also, if you need a function to generate a random string (depends on PHP 7 or random_compat):

```
/**
 * Note: See https://paragonie.com/b/JvICXzh_jhLyt4y3 for an alternative implementation
 */
function random_string($length = 26, $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567')
{
    if ($length < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Length must be a positive integer');
    }
    $str = '';
    $alphamax = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    if ($alphamax < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid alphabet');
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $alphabet[random_int(0, $alphamax)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Demo code: https://3v4l.org/DOjNE

Comment: It returns error: Fatal error: `Call to undefined function random_int() in` at line:       `$str .= $alphabet[random_int(0, $alphamax)];`

Comment: You need random_compat or PHP 7.

Comment: I uploaded `/lib`folder from random_compat script  to my server and included `random.php` in code. Now I get back to the error: `int(2) string(200) "is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed path(s):`

Comment: I saw that in `random.php` the order is: 1. `libsodium if available`
 2. `fread() /dev/urandom if available`
 3. `mcrypt_create_iv($bytes, MCRYPT_CREATE_IV)`
 4. `COM('CAPICOM.Utilities.1')->GetRandom()`
 5. `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. I will skip over option 2.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved for me two things: security and error fix.

Comment: My host has `PHP  5.6.16` and that was triggering the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_int()`. Random compat script solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your host doesn't support random_int() you can use a function which I made for myself.

```
function generateRandomString($length, $secureRand = false, $chars="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") {
    if (!function_exists("random_int") && $secureRand) {
        function random_int($min, $max) {
            $range = $max - $min;
            if ($range <= 0) return $min;

            $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
            $bytes = (int)($log / 8) + 1;
            $filter = (int)(1 << ((int)($log + 1))) - 1;
            do {
                $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes, $s)));
                if (!$s) continue;
                $rnd = $rnd & $filter;
            } while ($rnd > $range);

            return $min + $rnd;
        }
    }

    $charsCount = strlen($chars) - 1;
    $output = "";
    for ($i=1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        if ($secureRand)
            $output .= $chars[random_int(0, $charsCount)];
        else
            $output .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $charsCount)];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

If you need a secure random string (e.g. random passwords):

```
generateRandomString(8, true);
```

this will give you a 8 lenght string.